# Lodash, find indexes of all matching elements

Tags: typescript, lodash

Using lodash, how to get the array of indexes of all matching elements?
As example:

```
Animals = [{Name: 'Dog', Id: 0},
          {Name: 'Cat', Id: 1},
          {Name: 'Mouse', Id: 2},
          {Name: 'Horse', Id: 3},
          {Name: 'Pig', Id: 3}]
```

And then I want to find indexes of all elements with `Id == 3`.

Expected output:

```
Indexes = [3,4];
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a loop of some kind.

Comment: there is no other way?

Comment: `_.each` is a loop.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a short solution:

```
Indexes = _.keys(_.pickBy(Animals, {Id: 3}))
```

output:

```
Indexes = ["3", "4"]
```

---

Use `pickBy` to pick element, and `keys` to get indexes.

`pickBy` is for object

> `_.pickBy(object, [predicate=_.identity])`
>
> > Creates an object composed of the object properties predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with two arguments: (value, key).
>
> https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pickBy

But when use on array, it return a object like

```
{
  3: {Name: "Horse", Id: 3},
  4: {Name: "Pig", Id: 3}
}
```

use `_.keys` on this object to get all keys in string array

```
["3", "4"]
```

If you want to get number array, use `_.map`

```
_.map(_.keys(_.pickBy(Animals, {Id:3})), Number)
```

You will get

```
[3, 4]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: this does not explain the idiomatic use of `pickBy` where instead of a predicate function you actually pass an object literal `{Id: 3}`. This idiomatic use is also undocumented in lodash and I can't figure out where it originated from.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
_.filter(_.range(animals.length), (i) => animals[i].id === 3);
```

id === 3 is the filter condition defined in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straight-forward way is to break it down: 1) we need to find out which objects have an ID of 3, 2) get rid of everything else, and 3) grab the indexes we're interested in.

```
_.chain(animals)
    .map((animal, i)=> [i, animal.id === 3])
    .filter(pair=> pair[1])
    .map(pair=> pair[0])
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_.filter(
  _.map(Animals, (animal, index) => animal.id === 3 ? index : -1), 
  (index) => index >= 0
)
```

edit: animal.id === 3 is the filter condition defined in the question above.

Comment: Please add some context to the answer as to what your line of code is doing. This will help future visitors if it is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's what reduce is for:

```
_.reduce(Animals, function(result, value, key) {
          if(value.Id == 3) result.push(key);
 }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @AliYang answer with chain and for me, it looks more readable:

```
const findAllIndexes = <T>(array: Array<T>, predicate?: ValueKeyIteratee<T>) => {
  return chain(array)
    .pickBy(predicate)
    .keys()
    .map(Number)
    .value();
}
```

This implementation is with TS and the `ValueKeyIteratee` type comes from lodash, you can see it is used by lodash's `pickBy`