# react js lodash search subarray and want to return count of values

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have a react js app and using lodash to search thru a collection array which has subarray to find a value like myId:4, the structure looks something like this

```
myList: [ {  
  id: 0,
  rows: [{ status: [{value: 3}]
},
{
  id: 1,
  rows: [{ status: [{value: 1}]
}
]
```

I want to search all the status subarray for value:1

I tried using using _.findIndex and _.find like

```
_.findIndex(myList.rows, {value:1})>= 3

_.find(myList.rows, {value:1})
```

Both return the 1st match but not all the matches

After playing with find and findIndex it only finds the first record but not all the records.

Is there a lodash call like findAll? or is there a way to sum up all the subarray record count with that value I am searching for.

Thanks

Comment: Use `_.find` to get all the results

Answer (score 1):

Found this at another post: [Lodash, find indexes of all matching elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044587/lodash-find-indexes-of-all-matching-elements)

*.map(*.keys(_.pickBy(Animals, {Id:3})), Number)

Comment: So it's a duplicate question?